# Transmission and available disk space

Tags: disk-space, handbrake, transmission

I used Transmission to get a file which was part of a set of large files. Before opening the torrent, I checked the disk space :

```
df -h /dev/sda5
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       320G  246G   58G  81% /
```

After opening the torrent, I unchecked all the files I didn't want. The predicted size of the resulting download was 3 Gb.

Shortly after, HandBrake paused with a "no space left on device" error message. It didn't need 55 Gb, it only needed about 2 Gb.

I checked, and :

```
df -h /dev/sda5
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       320G  299G  5.4G  99% /
```

I'm not tossing about 50 Gb files, the only explanation I see is that Transmission did not only set aside disk space for the file I told it to download, it set aside disk space for all the large files of the torrent.

Is this explanation correct, please ? How can I stop it from happening again ?

My current workaround is to run Transmission and HandBrake one after the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Transmission and where did you get it from?

Comment: my guess is that you are correct, the storage is being preallocated before you are able to exclude files, and does not adjust it when you uncheck files. I suspect this is on purpose, because including/excluding files during the time the transfer is occuring is common. you might for instance uncheck all the files but the one you are most interested in, and then as it is completing, check other files in the torrent. the software would have to go back to allocate additional space, and in cases that could cause it to become unclear where the contents should be placed in the preallocated space.

Comment: Keep in mind, that a Torrent does not transmit "files" per se. Think of it more like the system preallocates a matrix of 2MB boxes, and each chunk of the torrent downloaded fits into one of those. the boxes will not be filled in a predictable order (they are dynamically determined based on the state of the swarm and your node in it), so dynamically changing storage allocation will change the dimensions of the grid, and confuse what chunks are associated with what data.